# make the textfield to be the first responder again

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
  [sender resignFirstResponder];
  [sender becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I have a UItextField object, and link the "Did End On Exit" to the "textFieldDoneEditing" action. After I press the Done button on the keyboard, why is it dismissed?

Comment: What is the purpose of resining keyboard and opening in the next line

Comment: [sender resignFirstResponder]; will resign the textfield. I wont undrstand why u calling both [sender resignFirstResponder]; [sender becomeFirstResponder]; what exactly do u wanna do inside this function?

Comment: Actually i find that the keyboard is not always come up when the textfield become first responder. When the textfield is first responder and the keyboard is dismissed, how could i get the keyboard on the screen again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method call another method like bellow code

in `yourViewController.h` file just define bellow method

```
-(void)MykeyBoardUp;
```

and in .m file

```
-(void)MykeyBoardUp{
      [yourtextFieldobject becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

after then in your .m file in bellow method just call this method like this

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
  [sender resignFirstResponder];
  [self performSelector:@selector(MykeyBoardUp) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
}
```

May this help you......

Answer (score 1):

in the above code, when you run `[sender resignFirstResponder]` keypad will hide
so calling next method is of no use

but if you still want to get keypad again, call it using `UITextField` object
i.e.

if in .h

`IBOulet UITextField *txt;`

then call
`[txt becomeFirstResponder]`

but still i don't understand, what is your purpose.